# How do I deal with data with 50% missing value for a specific dimension?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I have a dataset with 50 thousand records. 50% percent of the records don't have gender and birth dates.

I wish to analyze age-group/gender item purchase preference.

Values are missing completely at random.

Should I delete, impute, ignore, or just create a different model?

Lastly, can I still draw a valid conclusion using a model with 50% of missing values removed?

Comment: How do you know it's MCAR?

Comment: With that much of data missing, there's no way it could be MCAR. You should split the data up if when you need to use those variables and conduct two analyses.

Comment: @Jon I mean, you could tell a story about a loss of 50% of the data that took place completely at random, but we're agreed that it's highly unlikely.

Comment: Hi guys, encoding department was split into two. 1st group included the birth dates while the 2nd group did not. Encoding happened on a per end-of-day basis where the documents were distributed to the two groups 50/50.

Comment: When I hear that data are missing about 50/50, my first thought is indeed that they could be missing for some random reason like that.

Comment: How were the documents split between encoding groups? Seems like at least a possibility that, for example, the early purchases for the day could have been given to group A and the later purchases to group B, unless someone actually shuffled them before distribution i.e. based on your description it's not impossible that one group has the morning data and another group the afternoon data, which doesn't seem MCAR.

Comment: @DHW when data is missing approx. 50% of the time, how could this be due to random chance? That's like saying, "50% of my savings just disappeared, I guess I must have dropped half on my way home by random chance".

Comment: @Jon I mostly work with survey data, in which a given question is randomly asked only half the time, just to keep survey length manageable. I second the above comment asking what might have influenced a given observation to go to one team rather than another, but I'd still say that when there's exactly 50% missing, it's less worrisome in itself than other patterns of missingness which could be due, for example, to respondents' motivations and deduction of our research intentions. Of course, it's all about the theory you're using the data to test. Even self-selection might not matter.

Comment: @DHW two things to consider are differences in *sampling design* and *survey design*. The first is interested in how sampling methodology (e.g. what proportion of the population is sampled). The latter is focused on topics like what questions should be asked, how, and how long is the survey. That said, if in a survey every question is treated as *iid*, seeing a specific question miss 50% does not support MCAR. If missingness is equally distributed across all questions, then maybe. But this does not seem to be the case here. Reference: Lohr, S. L. (1999). Sampling: Design and analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Can your conclusions be considered valid if you listwise-delete MCAR data? Certainly - especially if your coefficients prove significant and relationship direction is all you care about. On the other hand, if you have other variables on-hand (which may or may not be missing values) and those variables are likely to correlate with age and/or gender - which I bet is the case - then it begs the question of why you didn't do imputation. Or worse yet, one may wonder: did they do imputation but the results were less favorable for their argument and so they're hoping no one asks about it?

Because we know the data are MCAR, we would not "expect" the imputation to change the coefficients - but we also don't "expect" the estimated effects from any random sample to be higher or lower than the true effect, so that's expected values for you. The imputation may very well change the coefficient because it's correcting random sampling error in the available cases. And even if the coefficient doesn't change, then the imputed cases will increase your statistical power and tighten your confidence intervals - legitimately so, if you do the imputation correctly with a number of imputed datasets and pooled results.